# Web Scraping not get all the table

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote code that takes a table using BeautifulSoup and Selenium.

However, only part of the table is obtained. Rows and columns that do not appear when accessing the [website](http://mananciais.sabesp.com.br/HistoricoSistemas) are not obtained by the soup object.

I am sure that the problem occurs in the excerpt `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until (EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"contenttabledivjqxGrid")))`

... I tried several other alternatives, but none gave me the expected result (which is to load all the rows and columns of this table, before I changed the date with Selenium).

[image]

Follow the code:

```
import os
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

​from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

# Escolhe o driver Firefox com Profile e Options
driver = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
driver.set_preference('intl.accept_languages', 'pt-BR, pt')
driver.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', '2')
driver.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', 'false')
driver.set_preference('browser.download.dir', 'dwnd_path')
driver.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/octet-stream,application/vnd.ms-excel')

options = Options()
options.headless = False

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=driver, options=options)

# Cria um driver

site = 'http://mananciais.sabesp.com.br/HistoricoSistemas'
driver.get(site)


WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"contenttabledivjqxGrid")))
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

# Cabeçalho
header = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'jqx-grid-column-header'})
for i in header:
    print(i.get_text())


# Seleciona as relevantes
head = []
for i in header:
    if i.get_text().startswith(('Represa', 'Equivalente')):
        print('Excluído: ' + i.get_text())
    else:
        print(i.get_text())
        head.append(i.get_text())

print('-'*70)
print(head)
print('-'*70)
print('Número de Colunas: ' + str(len(head)))

# Valores
data = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'jqx-grid-cell'})
values = []
for i in data:
    print(i.get_text())
    values.append(i.get_text())


import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Convert data to numpy array
num = np.array(values)

# Currently its shape is single dimensional
n_rows = int(len(num)/len(head))
n_cols = int(len(head))
reshaped = num.reshape(n_rows, n_cols)

# Construct Table
pd.DataFrame(reshaped, columns=head)
```

I'm a just a hydrologist, and want get this reservoirs data. Some one can help me?

My result table, for now, is this:

[image]

Comment: I don't know the solution without digging into the code from the page you are scrapping. Basically, it only loads what you are viewing so your HTML response does not have all the data you want. There is probably some type of listener on the page (like JQuery) that loads more data as soon as you need it. If you look into that JQuery script, you may be able to scrape from whatever resource it queries.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just checked the website. In Firefox if you go to Developer Tools > Network and if you check the file with name "0" you will notice that the response of that file is a JSON file with all the information that you need (Image 1). In order to get this information you will have to follow the request Headers (Image 2)

**Image 1: Request Response**

[image: JSON Request Data]

**Image 2: Request Headers**

[image: headers]

You will need to perform a "GET" request to the website with these headers and the response if it is accepted, will be a JSON with all your data. Bear in mind that some request might ask for a cookie header, which you will need to be obtained before performing the request.

I don't know Beatutiful Soup really well, but I know that this is achievable with Scrapy or with the Request Library. I am pretty sure this will point you to the right direction.

Comment: where the answer itself ?

Comment: Ow!
Many thanks!
This is the way! Surely!

It's works! I forgot the BeautifulSoup and now studying how convert properly the Json to a dataframe!

Comment: I am glad, that this helped you! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the table is loaded dynamically and in the HTML is only the part of the table which is visible, so that's why you get only part of the data.
The possible solution would be to use scrollbars by Selenium and read data bit by bit.